# Handling notifications in android

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I would like to know what is best practice when operating with push notifications in particular GCM notifications. Where should I ignore the notification from the server side. That is to say the server only send notifications to active users or the client side where the server sends out notifications but the app ignores them based on whether the activity is open or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always better to decide at the server side which devices have active users, and only send notifications to them.

The reasons:

- You don't want to run any code in the client side if you are not going to do anything with the incoming GCM message, since that would just be a waste or battery life.
- It's better to reduce the number of messages your server sends to GCM server, since this way, the devices that should recieve and display the notifications will recieve them faster.